# Can Clang warn me when I use non-standard functions provided by the GNU C Library?

Tags: c, clang

I am writing a C program on OS X and compiling it with clang. I am quite new to C and I have come to understand that some functions like [`getline()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) are useful but non-standard. I would like to be able to compile the program on a system where the GNU C Library is not available. Not knowing exactly what functions are non-standard, I am hoping there is a command-line switch for clang to warn me whenever I use such functions. Is there?

Output from `clang --version`:

> Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)

Comment: [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) is standard; OSX is just badly outdated.

Comment: @R.. It still won't work on a non-POSIX compliant system.

Comment: @michielvoo [getline()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is part of POSIX.1 2008.

Comment: @R.. Not implementing POSIX.1 2008 is not “badly outdated.” Things move a little bit slower in industrial software where stability is more important than fancy new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) (see also: [XSH 2.2.1 POSIX.1 Symbols](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_01)) to request visibility of only a particular set of standard interfaces. In particular,

```
-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600
```

on the command line or

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
```

should expose POSIX base plus the XSI option for the outdated 2001 version of POSIX (the latest OSX supports). If you want just base, without XSI, define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to `200112L`.

Comment: Thanks, this works in clang. It prints "warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]"

Comment: Also add `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`. Implicit functions are not valid C and are always a serious programming error.

Comment: @R.. They are valid C89, but not valid C99. If OP compiles with `-std=c99` or invokes the compiler as `c99`, he should get an error. Nevertheless, POSIX contains language (dating back from when POSIX mandated C89) that supplying your own prototype for standard functions or calling them without prototype is undefined behavior.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think you're going based on outdated or misremembered information. POSIX clearly states that you can provide your own prototypes for any of the standard functions as long as they don't require types from their header. Calling without a declaration (note: this is different from without a prototype) is always a constraint violation the compile has to diagnose, not just UB.

Answer (score 2):

There is no command line switch to say 'tell me if this is nonstandard'. The most common way of developing code that needs to be compatible across a variety of platforms is the [gnu autotools suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system), which gives you a configuration script which checks for various functionality and allows you to code around it, or have the system give up before going any further.

Comment: Yes, there is. See feature test macros and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a feature-test-macro like `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`. Conforming implementations are required to hide any extensions (i.e. extra library functions) when `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is present and no implementation-defined feature-test macros (like `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_GNU_SOURCE`) are defined:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

If you try to use an extension and this macro is defined you either get a warning (ANSI mode) or an error (C99) mode, as the prototype for the function is not present.

For Mac OS X, there is no POSIX.1 2008 support. Therefore, you have to define the macro like this to get POSIX.1 2001 support:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
```

Notice that a couple of functions were removed in POSIX.1 2008, but that shouldn't matter as these functions are usually (read: always) present on the target system as it probably also supports POSIX.1 2001.

Comment: @R.. Added language about OS X.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, mostly due to the fact that pretty much any project that I know of usually makes a distinction between:

- the compiler
- the standard library
- the ABI library

and typically this 3 things are kept separated into different project and they are designed to not step into each other. Sometimes there is even a more fragmented vision about this, where the compiler is splitted into backend, frontend, and multiple other modular projects and plugins like what happens in the big llvm project with clang.

As Petesh already suggested, your best options is some building system with this kind of ability where you can script the behaviour of your building process and detect if a macro fails or not, or if the targeted system offers the X features or not.

My suggestion, especially for a beginner, is [cmake](http://www.cmake.org) and its own [`wiki`](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake) .